# Generating keys in RSA

Tags: rsa, public-key

I'm trying to learn how RSA works. From what I found online, I'm supposed to 
generate private key using Extended Euclidean algorithm.

I've managed to generate the public key, but don't know how to use EEA to generate the private key. How should I exactly input into EEA, and how to process the output?

Comment: $d = e^{-1} \bmod lcm(p-1, q-1)$, or alternatively, $d = e^{-1} \bmod (p-1)(q-1)$

Comment: @poncho Is $e^{-1}=\frac{1}{e}$ or does it have some other meaning?

Comment: $e^{-1}$ is that value such that $e \times e^{-1} \equiv 1 \bmod lcm(p-1, q-1)$.  EEA is an algorithm that can be used to find such values